# how can I change from view to view without a bar or navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm very new to iphone programming. I'm trying to write an application where I can slide one view off the screen composed of a label and an image, and another will appear. However, I don't want any bars or navcontrollers (atleast not visible ones) involved, anyone know how I can just load another view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good tutorial for you courtesy of Apple: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html

Also, here are all of the sample programs that Apple has created to help you along the way: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code